# A UDP server on PHP, troubles with ports

Tags: php, sockets, server, udp, port

Im trying to create a simple UDP server on php which initially will be receiving some dummy data. I've tried following some tutorials and now i can create and bind a socket. However when im using   `socket_recvfrom` for some reason the page just keeps loading and when i refresh it again, the port is taken and i cant bind the socket in that port anymore. below is my code and any answer is welcomed.
   `

```
if(!($sock=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
$errorcode = socket_last_error();
$errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

die("Couldnt create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "socket create OK";
if (!socket_bind($sock,"localhost",8880))
{
$errorcode = socket_last_error();
$errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

die("Couldnt bind socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
 }
echo "socket bind OK";

// while(1)
// {
$remote_ip ='';
$remote_port=0;
echo "waiting for data ... \n";
$r=socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port --". $buf;
// }

// socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: Simply refreshing your page will not terminate your php script until you define "False" the php ini configuration of ignore_user_abort, or setting it at runtime and defining a timeout for the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this function:

`if (false ===($tcpsock = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:8876",$errorno,$errstr)))
    echo"tcp socket failed : $errstr($errorno)\n";

if(false ===($connection = stream_socket_accept($tcpsock))) 
    echo "tcp accept failed!\n";
else echo "tcp accepted";`

And if you want a UDP socket, you just have to :`stream_socket_server("udp://127.0.0.1:8876",$errorno,$errstr)))`